# Getting error from the inkcanvase base 64 string

Tags: c#, wpf

Hello we are using InkCanvas control on the wpf page. And we are saving Base64String string in the database. See code

```
 private void submitButtonsCommand_Event(object sender)
    {
        byte[] sigByte;
        InkCanvas icSignature = sender as InkCanvas;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            icSignature.Strokes.Save(memoryStream);
            sigByte = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
        ServiceCallReportSignatureModel.SigCustomerSignature = Convert.ToBase64String(sigByte);
        UpdateRecord();
    }
```

And when we are retrieving data from the database and converting into the FromBase64String and after that when we creating image then we are getting the error.

```
 public Image LoadImage(base64string)
{
    //data:image/gif;base64,
    //this image is a single pixel (black)
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64string);

    Image image;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        image = Image.FromStream(ms);
    }

    return image;
}
```

I don't know why this is occurring. Please help me find out the error.
Our base64 string is : "AIwBAwxIEEWfARsCAAb/RjURAACAPx8JEQAAAAAAAPA/Cmwsh/EgR4kP+Etw/ojDWG7NZ8OZQxBN5otEzmU1mk04I7DnATcLHomzzUbxw/h3Dtp16yhlTQ2UsoTQh+uE64XgjsN6Js2UZpAZmFpmaZTKzzKZ4ctFmw3Mlmm0Bw9h/DtpTPKu79CYgm+VJqA="

> Actually we are taking signature from the ink canvas control and we want to display in the pdf when we need. So we want create image from the base 64 data but we are getting the error.

Comment: what error/exception do you get?

Comment: We are getting error of data mismatch.

Comment: Obviously this won't work. While you are storing a StrokeCollection in [*Ink Serialized Format*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590544(v=vs.110).aspx), you are trying to read a bitmap. These are two entirely different things.

Comment: Try to save the memory stream to disc and see if you can open the image. If you can't open it, that's the problem. It seems to me that you are saving a non-image and try to open it as an image.

Comment: @ Clemens have you any solution?

Comment: It isn't clear what exactly you are trying to do, but you may search StackOverflow (or the web) for something like "inkcanvas strokes bitmap". This has been asked and answered before.

Comment: Can I create image from the FileStream data? And how to save FileStream Data in the database. 
Will we need to generate string of FileStream Data? And We does not want to 
create image when we capturing the signature. We want to create image when we need. 
Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 2):

The [`StrokeCollection.Save(Stream)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590544(v=vs.110).aspx) method does not save a bitmap. Instead,

> The Save method saves the StrokeCollection as Ink Serialized Format (ISF).

You can restore the saved StrokeCollection by passing a `Stream` with the saved data to the [`StrokeCollection(Stream)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms522846(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor.

Comment: Can I create image from the FileStream data? And how to save FileStream Data in the database? Will we need to generate base 64 string of FileStream Data? And We does not want to create image when we capturing the signature. We want to create image when we need. Is this possible and how?

Comment: Actually we are taking signature from the ink canvas control and want to display in the pdf when we need.